# WifiWizard2 scan returns empty array

Tags: android, cordova, wifi

I'm trying to scan for wifi networks

```
WifiWizard2.scan().then(function (results) {
  console.log("SCANRESULTS", results);
}, function () {
  console.log("TOUGH LUCK");  
});
```

But every time I get an empty array

> SCANRESULTS []

How am I doing this wrong?

I can confirm there are at least 20 networks around me.

I'm using an android 7 device if it makes any difference.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Sender class

```
    public class WifiFunction {

    private final String tag = WifiFunction.class.getSimpleName();
    private WifiManager wifiManager;

    public List<WifiDetail> getListofWifi(Context context) {

        List<WifiDetail> wifiDetails = new ArrayList<>();
        List<ScanResult> results = wifiManager.getScanResults();
        Log.d(tag,"Wifi Details " + wifiManager.getScanResults().size());
        for (ScanResult result : results) {
            wifiDetails.add(new WifiDetail(result.BSSID, result.SSID));
            Log.d(tag, result.BSSID + result.SSID);
        }
        return wifiDetails;
    }

    public void startScan(Context context)
    {
        wifiManager = (WifiManager) context.getSystemService(Context.WIFI_SERVICE);
        wifiManager.startScan();
        IntentFilter filter = new IntentFilter();
        filter.addAction(SCAN_RESULTS_AVAILABLE_ACTION);
        context.registerReceiver(new resultReciever(this),filter);
    }

}
```

Receiver class

```
       public class resultReciever extends BroadcastReceiver {

    private WifiFunction wifiFunction;

    resultReciever(WifiFunction wifiFunction)
    {
        this.wifiFunction = wifiFunction;
    }

    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        Log.d("Receiver","started");
        wifiFunction.getListofWifi(context);
    }
}
```

From Main Activity I am just calling:

```
(new WifiFunction()).startScan(this);
```

Manifest

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE"/>
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisiion.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permisiion.ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION" />

<application
    android:allowBackup="true"
    android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
    android:label="@string/app_name"
    android:roundIcon="@mipmap/ic_launcher_round"
    android:supportsRtl="true"
    android:theme="@style/AppTheme">
    <activity android:name=".MainActivity">
        <intent-filter>
            <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

            <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
        </intent-filter>
    </activity>
    <receiver android:name=".resultReciever"/>
</application>
```

Runtime Permission :

```
   private boolean checkPermission() {

    List<String> permissionsList = new ArrayList<String>();

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_WIFI_STATE);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.CHANGE_WIFI_STATE);
    }

    if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION) != PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED) {
        permissionsList.add(Manifest.permission.ACCESS_COARSE_LOCATION);
    }

    if (permissionsList.size() > 0) {
        ActivityCompat.requestPermissions(this, permissionsList.toArray(new String[permissionsList.size()]),
                1);
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public void onRequestPermissionsResult(int requestCode, String[] permissions,
                                       int[] grantResults) {
    switch (requestCode) {
        case 1:
            (new WifiFunction()).startScan(this);
            break;
    }
}
```

This should work. Tried it with the full code.

Comment: I'm using cordova. Anyway it asked me for location access and I granted it, still nothing.

Comment: I just checked my generated android manifest file and ACCESS_FINE_LOCATION is there as well.

Comment: You should check this one, I wrote the code and tried out and got the result

Comment: Thank you so much for your effort. It appears the code is working, on another device which is Android 10. It appears there is some problem with some devices...

Comment: Congratulations, hope your app is successful!

Answer (score 0):

In later versions of Android, you have to enable GPS. I normally keep my GPS switched off in the hope of preventing tracking by unscrupulous apps.
Code similar to the above worked for me only when I turned on GPS on my mobile phone.